# Saxon.net Memory issue

Tags: validation, saxon, schematron

I am facing memory issues with Saxon.net I am using Saxon 9.8.0.7
Following is my code snippet. what can be improved?

This method is called for each XSLT, so it can be called 3-4 time for validating single document

```
 public Stream TransformToStream(Stream xmlstream, string xsltLocation)
        {
            Stream resultStream = new MemoryStream();
            try
            {
                // Create a Processor instance.
                Processor processor = new Processor();


                // Load the source document
                var documentbuilder = processor.NewDocumentBuilder();
                documentbuilder.BaseUri = new Uri("http://dummy.base.uri/");

                XdmNode input = documentbuilder.Build(xmlstream);

                XsltExecutable exec = null;
                // Create a transformer for the stylesheet.
                var compiler = processor.NewXsltCompiler();

 compiler.ErrorList = new 
               System.Collections.Generic.List<Exception>();

               string filename = xsltLocation.Substring(7);

 exec = compiler.Compile(new Uri(filename));

  XsltTransformer transformer = exec.Load();

                    // Set the root node of the source document to be the initial context node
                    transformer.InitialContextNode = input;

                    // Create a serializer
                    Serializer serializer = new Serializer();
                    serializer.SetOutputStream(resultStream);

                    // Transform the source XML to System.out.
                    transformer.Run(serializer);
  }
                catch (Exception exx)
                {
}
```

Comment: Can you explain in some detail how the "memory problems" manifest themselves? If you have a single document to which you want to apply 3 or 4 stylesheets, why do you need to build the `XdmNode input` each time, can't you build it once? And what kind of transformation result do you need or how do you process that MemoryStream you return?

Comment: Is there any reason you have tagged this "Schematron"? It's not mentioned anywhere in the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is much that can be improved in your code, but I have no idea whether the improvements are relevant to the problems you are seeing.

Basically, the split between Processor - XsltCompiler - XsltExecutable - XdmNode - XsltTransformer is there to allow you to share whatever can be shared. You should always try to share the Processor (most applications should create a single Processor and reuse it). If you run the same stylesheet on multiple source documents, the XsltExecutable should be shared. If you run different stylesheets on the same source document, the XdmNode should be shared. And so on.

As for your memory problems, as with all performance problems, the devil will be in the detail and you need to drill down to find the needle in the haystack that is causing the pain. I'm less familiar with .NET tools than with Java tools, but the methodology is the same. Measure how the memory usage changes as the work progresses, so you can isolate the steps that are responsible. Measure how the memory usage changes when you change the input, e.g. how it correlates with source document size. And use heap analysis tools to discover what objects are actually occupying the memory.

Very often you can tackle a performance problem from two ends. (a) finding out what aspects of the workload cause the observed metric (e.g. memory usage) to vary? (b) breaking down the top-level problem metric into finer-grained metrics, for example the space occupied by the compiled stylesheet, the space occupied by source document trees, and the space occupied by the result document (which you appear, for some reason, to be holding in a MemoryStream.)

The other thing that's critical about performance problems is that they need to be quantified. You need to quantify your requirements/expectations, and quantify the actual metric against the requirement. It's remarkable that your question contains no numerical information whatsoever.